# Twig file to Tpl conversion of opencart

Tags: twig, opencart, opencart-3

```
{% if languages|length >= 1 %}
```

this is the twig file code . how can we write this code in tpl file . i am converting opencart 3.0.2.0 theme into opencart 2.3.0.2 .
I am facing problem to solve  | this sign . mean how can i convert this line in tpl exactly .thanks

Comment: You can convert your Twig code to PHP or TPL here : https://www.easycodetools.com/tool/twig-to-php-converter here, is online twig to PHP converter ( online twig to TPL converter )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `count` function:

```
<?php if(count($languages) >= 1){ ?>

<?php } ?>
```